# Laravel 5 update multiple rows with different values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have been searching everywhere for a solution to this, I hope someone has already solved it or has some good ideas for improvement.

I am using Laravel 5 and I have come accross a situation where I need to update many rows with new values. Right now I'm doing a for-loop for all those rows to update them and I would like to optimize this so that I don't run many sql queries. Here's an example code:

```
<?php

   //Well, the original code looks better than this, but the concept is the same

   $myrows = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
   $myvalues = [45,543,657,574,234,26457,2462,897,234,89032];

   for($i=0;$i<count($myrows);$i++) {
      MyClass::where('id', $myrows[$i])->update(['myColumn' => $myvalues[$i]]);
   }

?>
```

Obviously this will execute 10 queries (the same amount as the rows I want to update), but I want to do this with only one query, for optimization purposes. I am aware of the ability to update many rows at the same time with whereIn(...)->update(...) but with this method you can only update all rows to the same value, not different ones like in my example.

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: if you want to update columns with different values I don't see any way around optimizing that. It should be planned from the database design if so.

Comment: Looks like it, alright thanks ! Just one question, how do you mean "planned from the database design" ? Not with code but with a different database connection type ? I am currently using MySQL. Or do you mean the way I save my data in columns ?

Comment: By database design - depend on your type of data and the need to update them together - I meant you could serialized them in one coulmn instead. If that is possible by your database structre and purposes of it use ex. Settings options

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not the matter of Laravel QueryBuilder. If you could do your stuff in one SQL query only, you almost could do it with Laravel.

Comment: After trying to do it with raw SQL query, I came to the same conclusion. Thanks !

Comment: This answer doesn't specify what and how to do multi row update.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myRows = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
$myValues = [45,543,657,574,234,26457,2462,897,234,89032];

if (empty($myRows)) {
    // return or throw exception
    return;
}
if (count($myRows) != count($myValues) {
    // in case of dynamic values for $myRows/$myValues
    return;
}
$cases = [];
$cases[] = "CASE id";

for ($myRows as $row) {
    $cases[] = "WHEN {$row} THEN ?";  
}

$cases = implode(" ", $cases);
$ids = implode(",", $myRows);

DB::update("UPDATE `my_table` SET `my_column` = {$cases} END WHERE `id` in ({$ids})", $myValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

in SQL every single query is executing in sequence.

```
foreach ( array_combine($myrows,$myvalues) a $id => $val){
          MyClass::find($val)->update(['myColumn' => $val]);
}
```

only thing you can do is to append queries, and send it once,
something like this:

```
$builder = DB::table((new MyClass)->getTable());
$sql='';

foreach ( array_combine($myrows,$myvalues) a $id => $val){
          $sql .= $builder->getGrammar()->insert($builder->where('id', $id),['myColumn' => $val]);
}
DB::connection()->getPdo()->prepare($sql)->execute();
```